# In MySQL, can I setup my table to automatically encrypt data as it is inserted

Tags: mysql, encryption

I want to set it up so that, the second a piece of data is inserted into a field in my MySQL table, it is automatically encrypted using an AES private key.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to modify data directly before or after an insert or update, you create a trigger with your desired logic.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter how you connect to the db. (Ofcourse, the data will not be encrypted as it is sent over the database connection)

Comment: ensure the connection to the MySQL server is encrypted, though: you probably don't want to send confidential data over any network in plain text